# How to optimize Spark Streaming process for reading large data sets from Kafka queue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I read streaming data from Kafka and process it using Spark Streaming. The amount of data is around 1 MB every 30 minutes.
I set the batch interval equal to 5 minutes. When I launch the Spark Streaming job with the smallest offset, it should process around 500Mb. For some reason it takes very long time to process it (around 5 hours), though the processing operations are not complex (some filtering of data based on fields and grouping).
I wonder if it has something to do with the parameters of `spark submit` command and Kafka parameters in my code. For example, I was reading [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html) about the need to set well-balanced values of `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` of Kafka Consumer in Scala. Should I maybe limit the batch size saying that all these 500Mb should be split into batches of 1Mb and processed separately? Or should I set `fetch.message.max.bytes` to e.g. `1000000` bytes (1Mb)? Or maybe it makes sense to add `Thread.sleep(3000)` right after `ssc.start()` and `ssc.awaitTermination()` in order to give some time for the forgetting old RDDs to complete.

My spark submit command looks as follows:

```
    spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g \
    --num-executors 2 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch" \
    --class org.test.TestRunner \
    --queue "myqueue" \
    testprocess.jar \
    "20" "5"
```

Comment: If the code is from your previous question, that should definitely not take 5 hours to complete a batch. Can you share you graph here as well?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: The code is much longer than the one shown in the question that you refer to. But anyway I don't think that it should take 5 hours. How can I create the graph you are asking about?